# How to creare ArrayList and skip it through the loop

Tags: c#

I want to write a card exchange game. I have an Arraylist of Colors in which values start from -1 to 6. Each element of this array implies id colors. There is also an ArrayList Player Properties in which cards with colors are stored.  I need to create an ArrayList with eight zeros that will imply id Colors. Next, skip the ArrayList Player Properties through this array and if there is some element in the array, then increase the ArrayList Colors index by +1.

Eg:

```
ArrayList Colors =new ArrayList(){-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
ArrayList Player Properties = new ArrayList(){0,4,6};
This array should imply that its element is an element of the Colors array
ArrayList buffer = new ArrayList(){0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
If an array comes to the input in this form: {0,4,6};
Then the index of this array is added by +1, like this: {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1};
```

How do I implement this in code?

I don't have any code examples because I don't know how to implement it, sorry in advance that I didn't provide more code, I really need help, thank you all in advance for your help

Comment: ArrayList is very, very old now; is there a particular reason you're using it?

Comment: @CaiusJard there are no specific reasons

Comment: Why are there 10 elements in`{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0}` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard this is a mistake, I fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Linq function `Contains` to check if a value is present in an array. Something like this:

```
    var colors = new int[] { -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    var playerProperties = new int[] { 0, 4, 4, 6 };
    var result = colors.Select(c => playerProperties.Where(x => x == c).Count());
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

prints `0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1`

Comment: I think the intent is to keep adding 1 in the place values where properties match. So next time around the result could be for example `0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2` if the properties where `{3, 4, 6}`.

Comment: @JAlex yes, if an array containing {1,1,2,4} suddenly arrives, will the index of the number one change to two? I need to increase in this case if there are repetitions

Comment: @JAlex is it possible to modify this option to work for me? I understand that you need to do everything right, but how to do this functionality based on the already available data? if I start doing everything right, then something may break in the process and then come to redo a lot

Comment: @YamaLomama I updated the answer to give the count of occurences in playerProperties

Comment: @HansKilian Thank you so much! This solution suits me very well. I am glad that there are people like you in the world! All the best to you! You're the best!

Comment: This answer is no different to what JAlex and I posted

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the card values that you accumulate.

Since this is C# you better start thinking of a data model for each player. There are two arrays to consider, one with the card values: -1,0,..6 and one with the card counts, how many of each card a player has.

Here is how this would play out:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var player1 = new Player("Player1");

        Console.WriteLine(player1);            
        // Player1 : 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

        player1.Hand(0,4,6);
        Console.WriteLine(player1);
        // Player1: 0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1
    }
}
```

You can to this point with the following `Player` class that handles the logic inside the `.Hand()` method.

```
public class Player
{
    public static readonly int[] CardValues = { -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    public Player(string name)
    {
        CardCounts = new int[CardValues.Length];
        Name = name;
    }
    public int[] CardCounts { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public void Hand(params int[] cards)
    {
        foreach (var card in cards)
        {
            int index = Array.IndexOf(CardValues, card);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                CardCounts[index] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} : {string.Join(",", CardCounts)}";
    }
}
```

---

Note that `ArrayList` is really old technology, and not type safe. In it place there is `List<>`, but in this case the length of the array is fixed since there is a finite set of card values, and that does not change, so no need for a collection, as a plain old `Array` would suffice.

Comment: *and not type safe* - well, that's not really true..

Comment: @CaiusJard you can show me how to do it right, just writing a comment is not the best thing, I'm a beginner and I may not understand everything that is written in the comments

Comment: I wasn't saying that JAlex's answer is wrong, just that it's a  bit misleading to say that ArrayList isn't type safe. I do agree that ArrayList should not be used. I don't have any problem with the main content of the answer, though I think I would have shortcut it a bit.

Comment: @YamaLomama - to do it "right" there is a lot more that can be done here. For one I would ditch the integers to distinguish card colors, and define an `enum` with the values. The methods under `System.Enum` then allow you to convert between symbols, integers and strings. Add a `[Description()]` attribute and you can have a user readable string for use in the UI.

Comment: @CaiusJard - how is `ArrayList` type safe? It casts everything into `object`, even value types and it is up to the consumer to handle the type conversions manually.

Comment: What does "type safety" mean, to you?

Comment: @JAlex Thank you, you helped me a lot, it's clear that you understand C# very well, thank you for your time on this question!

Comment: @CaiusJard - https://stackoverflow.com/q/2437469/13813219

Comment: @JAlex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984499/is-arraylist-is-typesafe-or-strongly-typed/17984521#17984521

Answer (score 0):

Because your array is a fixed representation:

```
var Colors = new []{-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
var PlayerProperties = new []{0,4,6};
var buffer = new []{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

You can calculate which indexes in the buffer should be set to 1

```
foreach(var pp in PlayerProperties)
  buffer[pp+1] += 1;
```

Value 0 always occurs at index 1. Value 4 always occurs at index 5. Value 6 always occurs at index 7. Thus the formula is `value+1`..