# Compare Two Jagged Arrays in C# for "except"

Tags: c#, linq, console-application

I'm trying to find the members of two arrays where they appear in one but not the other.
I've read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0) and I think while I understand it I'm doing something incorrectly.

Assume the following simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[][] currentLocation = new int[][]
                {
                    new int[] { 11, 10 },
                    new int[] { 11, 11 },
                    new int[] { 11, 12 },
                    new int[] { 11, 13 },
                };
        int[][] proposedLocation = new int[][]
                {
                    new int[] { 11, 12 },
                    new int[] { 11, 13 },
                    new int[] { 11, 14 },
                    new int[] { 11, 15 },
                };
        
        IEnumerable<int[]> onlyInFirstSet = proposedLocation.Except(currentLocation);
        foreach (int[] number in onlyInFirstSet)
            Console.WriteLine(number[0].ToString() + ","+number[1].ToString());
    }
}
```

Now what I'd hope/think/expect to see would be:

```
11,14
11,15
```

...because in the `proposedLocation` these are the only ones that don't appear in `currentLocation`
However I'm actually getting:

```
11,12
11,13
11,14
11,15
```

(i.e. the whole of `proposedLocation`)

**Question:** how do I extract values that only appear in `proposedLocation`? I'd be beneficial if I could somehow retain the `int[][]` rather than an odd bit of `string` while at it but that's a bonus.

Comment: Pay attention to the official [documentation for `Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except). It has an overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.  You can create a custom equality comparer that equality-compares the content of the int-arrays (for example either with the help of a loop or Linq's SequenceEquals method). Then pass your equality comparer to the Except method, and Bob should be your uncle. If you got the equality comparer working to your satisfaction, feel free to self-answer the question... ;-)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace - thanks but admittedly that is waaaay above my level of knowledge. :) [to write a custom equality comparer that is].

Comment: Note if the inner array values go together, like `11,10` are different from `11,11`, like coordinates, the use a structure with x/y values in place of the inner array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an `int[] { 11, 10}` for a location isn't sufficient for a few reasons.

- First, all arrays have reference semantics, which means an equality check does not check values but for reference equality (if they are the same object in memory). This means the following check produces false.

  ```
  int[] a = new[] { 1,2 };
  int[] b = new[] { 1,2 };
  if( a == b || a.Equals(b) ) 
  {
      // this will never happen
  }
  ```
- Second, there is enforcement of two coordinates for each location. Each row in a jagged array can have different number of columns. This makes for some awkward coding to be thorough in your code.
- Third, the values of an array can be changed at any time, without you having a way to prevent this. Consider the code

  ```
  int[] a = new[] { 1, 2};
  a[0] = 10;
  ```

  This can cause bugs as locations you think have specific values, due to a programming error, can easily change locations.
- Lastly, if you want to display the values of a location, you can't just call `Console.WriteLine(array)` because it won't display the values, and thus you need a loop, or use `string.Join()` to create a displayable array.

#### Location as a struct (X,Y)

All of the above, combined, call for a different approach. I suggest using a structure that can store two values (just as the array), only two values, no more or less, can check for equality with other locations, and finally has a built-in way to convert to a string for display.

```
public readonly struct Location : IEquatable<Location>
{
    public Location(int x, int y) : this()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public override string ToString() => $"({X},{Y})";

    #region IEquatable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(Location)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Location item)
        {
            return Equals(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="Location"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(Location other)
    {
        return this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="Location"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
            unchecked
            {
                int hc = -1817952719;
                hc = (-1521134295) * hc + this.X.GetHashCode();
                hc = (-1521134295) * hc + this.Y.GetHashCode();
                return hc;
            }                
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Location target, Location other) { return target.Equals(other); }
    public static bool operator !=(Location target, Location other) { return !target.Equals(other); }

    #endregion
}
```

Some key features of this structure are

- `X`, `Y` properties hold the values and are unchanging. A location is defined by its (x,y) values and they go in pairs together. The values are set at the constructor and are readonly.
- `Equals(Location other)` check for value equality (both x and y).
- `ToString()` automatically converts the structure to a string when needed. This allows calls like `Console.WriteLine(location)` to produce the results `(11,14)` for example.
- LINQ operations automatically take advantage of `Equals()` function as we forward the generic `Equals(object)` to the specific `Equals(Location)` function.
- The `GetHashCode()` function you can ignore for now. It is there because it is required by certain collections, and it guarantees that if two locations are different, that they will have different hash-codes.

#### Program

Now to test for the use case described in the question

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Location[] currentLocation = new Location[]
        {
            new Location( 11, 10 ),
            new Location( 11, 11 ),
            new Location( 11, 12 ),
            new Location( 11, 13 ),
        };
        Location[] proposedLocation = new Location[]
        {
            new Location( 11, 12 ),
            new Location( 11, 13 ),
            new Location( 11, 14 ),
            new Location( 11, 15 ),
        };

        var list = Enumerable.Except(proposedLocation, currentLocation).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

with output as expected:

```text
(11,14)
(11,15)
```

Note that due to the operation of `Except()` and the definition provided, you need to subtract the fist list from the second list, and that is way I am calling `.Except(proposedLocation, currentLocation)` and not the other way around.

#### Location as a tuple (int,int)

You can achieve the same result, by using a `Tuple` of two `int` values. Actually a `ValueTuple<int,int>` would have the exact same behavior as our custom structure `Location` above.

The code below has the exact same result as before, does not require a custom structure, and keeps [type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437490/380384), as opposed to a solution that casts locations as `object`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currentLocation = new List<(int X, int Y)>()            
        {
            ( 11, 10 ),
            ( 11, 11 ),
            ( 11, 12 ),
            ( 11, 13 ),
        };
        var proposedLocation = new List<(int X, int Y)>()
        {
            ( 11, 12 ),
            ( 11, 13 ),
            ( 11, 14 ),
            ( 11, 15 ),
        };

        var list = Enumerable.Except(proposedLocation, currentLocation).ToArray();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        // Output:
        // (11,14)
        // (11,15)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer the syntactic sugar `(int X, int Y)` over `ValueTuple<int, int>`.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with [-MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19858830/myskullcaveisadarkplace). However, if you want to achieve this with a workaround, refer to the below.

Instead of an jagged array, use an object.

```
var currentLocation = new object[]
                        {
                        new  { a = 11, b = 10 },
                        new  { a = 11, b = 11 },
                        new  { a = 11, b = 12 },
                        new  { a = 11, b = 13 }
                        };
    
                var proposedLocation = new object[]
                        {
                        new  { a = 11, b = 12 },
                        new  { a = 11, b = 13 },
                        new  { a = 11, b = 14 },
                        new  { a = 11, b = 15 }
                        };
    
                var a = proposedLocation.Except(currentLocation);
```

Comment: Gave it an upvote as it works - not marking it as "approved answer" just yet tho' as it's a workaround. Thank you :) -- (if nobody else replies I'll mark it as AA later.)

Comment: Using an array of  `object` is highly discouraged in C#. You can achieve the same using a `ValueTuple` instead of anonymous types BTW.