# List of Lists with different type

Tags: c#, .net, list

I want to add Lists with different types to a list. This is my approach:

```
struct Column
{
    public string title;
    public List<dynamic> col;
}

var signals = new List<Column>();
signals.Add(new Column {title = "stringCol", col = new List<string>() });
signals.Add(new Column {title = "doubleCol", col = new List<double>() });
```

It says that `List<string>` can't be converted to `List<dynamic>`. I also tried using templates, but I didn't get it running.

Comment: You can't do this unless you make all the lists the same type (e.g. `dynamic`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `object` instead of `dynamic`, you will have list of `object` which you can later cast to desired type.

```
struct Column
{
    public string title;
    public List<object> col;
}

var signals = new List<Column>();
signals.Add(new Column {title = "stringCol", col = new List<object> {new List<string>() }});
signals.Add(new Column {title = "doubleCol", col = new List<object> {new List<double>() }});
```

Why not dynamic? read here: [dynamic vs object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442821/dynamic-vs-object-type)

Abstract:

> If you use dynamic you're opting into dynamic typing, and thus opting
>   out of compile-time checking for the most part.

So it means `dynamic` type will be calculated at runtime and it does not mean "any type" it means "some type defined at runtime"

Comment: Was about to edit your answer but you beat me it. Have a +1 instead :)

Comment: Adding to your answer i would suggest a third property in the struct to identify the type of the list. I was about answering the exact same like you did :)

Comment: @Dom84 it is an option, great suggestion :)

Comment: How do I access the `List<string>`? I tried `signals[0].col.Add("string")`, but this adds an element to the `List<object>`.

Comment: @Henste yes it does, but underlying type of this `object` is `string`

Comment: `new List<object> {new List<string>() }` -- why would you ever do this? `string` plays absolutely no role here. And also, `dynamic` definitely means "any type" because it means `object` and `object` *can* be any type.

Comment: @Jon this `new List<object> {new List<string>() }` is just to present a possibility to add `List` of any type to this list.

Comment: I still could do `signals[0].col.Add(new DateTime());`, although I only want to be able to add strings...