# How Boxing and Unboxing Work for Dynamic DataType in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, type-conversion, boxing, unboxing

I know about boxing and unboxing concept of C# for Type conversion . But How It works for Dynamic Variable in C# . How Type conversion takes place when we use dynamic variable . In Which way it is following the boxing and unboxing principles of c#

I think boxing and unboxing does not treat Dynamic type as object as They are not same . Don't know whether they are following same mechanism for boxing and unboxing or not
See this link [dynamic vs object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442821/dynamic-vs-object-type)

When you use dynamic, the entire expression is treated at compile time as a dynamic expression, which causes the compiler to treat everything as dynamic and get run-time binding.

this is because in below line str is dynamic

```
    dynamic str = "22/11/2013 10:31:45 +00:01";
    var withOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);
```

At compile time str is dynamic, the type of str get to know at runtime only that is the reason compiler treat withOffset as dynamic

Comment: The *dynamic* keyword is an alias for *object*.  Values are always boxed, objects are never boxed.  There is never a need to help, nor can you.

Comment: are you trying to say dynamic variable and objects are same  . i am not sure about this

Comment: is boxing and unboxing for dynamic as well as objects are same

Comment: i think dynamic and object are not same . see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442821/dynamic-vs-object-type

are you trying to say they are same with boxing and unboxing

Comment: They are the same at runtime, the CLR does not distinguish between dynamic and object.  So boxing behavior is identical.  It matters at compile time, using dynamic makes the C# compiler generate code to use the C# binder to the DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime).  Which optimizes dynamic code such as Reflection, late-bound COM and interop with languages like Python and Ruby.  Usually Reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Object and dynamics have the same behavior when it come to boxing and unboxing (you can check this in the IL code generated).

The main differences in this case, betwen those 2, is:

- The clr add some IL code at runtime, that determine it's real type and the operation that you can perform on it(payload).
- The compiler let you do:

  1.var withOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);

  2.DateTimeOffset withOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);

  3.DateTime withOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(str);

  But on runtime, the clr ensure type safety so if you write the case 3, it compile, but at runtime the clr will throw a RuntimeBinderException.

Hope it helps!