# how to use Option Strict On and Late Binding

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, com-interop, option-strict

I am trying to get some code to compile after switching Option Strict On. However I am using some Interop with VB6 and passing in a form object ByRef so Form.Caption fails and I can't convert it to type Form because a VB.NET Form doesn't have a caption property.

How can I can get the following to compile with Option Strict ON:

```
Public Sub EditFormLegacy(ByRef objForm As Object)

    objForm.Caption = objForm.Caption + " Edited"

End Sub
```

Is there any way to switch option strict off for specific methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net equivalent for C# 'dynamic' with Option Strict On](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-dynamic-with-option-strict-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't turn it off for a method, but you can turn if off for a form or class.  Just put "option strict off" at the top of the form.  Per MSDN - "If used, the Option Strict statement must appear in a file before any other source code statements."  HTH

Answer (score 0):

You *really* want to leave option Strict on, so I guess you should try a workaround. For example, get the form (with the caption) to store it's Caption in a seperate string, which can be recalled by the new class loading in the form.

Comment: I don't see how that would work because the .NET side will still not know what type of object is being passed