# Calling Python script from windows form

Tags: python, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ironpython, vb.net-2010

I'm an IronPython novice and would like some help.  I have a windows form that I have created in Visual Basic 2010 Express, which contains two text-boxes ('**txtNumber**' and '**txtResult**') and a button ('**btnSquare**').  What I want to do is be able to call the below Python script ('**Square.py**') on clicking the button on the form;

```
class SquarePython:

    def __init__(self, number):

        self.sq = number*number
```

This script should square the number that is input in to '**txtNumber**' and then output the result in to '**txtResult**'.  I know this is almost too simple, but I just need to know the basics.  Here's what I have so far in my VB code;

```
Imports Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Hosting
Imports IronPython.Runtime.Types

Public Class Square

    Private Sub btnSquare_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSquare.Click

        Dim runtime As ScriptRuntime = Python.CreateRuntime

        Dim scope As ScriptScope = runtime.ExecuteFile("Square.py")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, the code runs as it is.  But when I add the line -- Dim pythonType As PythonType = scope.GetVariable("SquarePython") -- I get an error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking at sq and not SquarePython, which is the class?

Comment: If I try that, I get the error "'ScopeStorage' object has no attribute 'sq'"

Comment: Ok, I am booting up my VS to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give an answer in C#, if you don't mind. But anyway it is very similar to `VB` version. For your code accessing `SquarePython` is very simple

```
ScriptEngine py = Python.CreateEngine();

ScriptScope scope = py.ExecuteFile("Square.py");

dynamic square = scope.GetVariable("SquarePython");

int result = (int)square(5);

Console.WriteLine(result.sq); //prints 25 as you might expected
```

But for simplicity, I would modify python code a little bit, like this

```
class SquarePython:
    def Square(self, number):
        return number * number
```

So that you don't have to create an object each time you compute. Code that retrieve variable and call method to square is given below:

```
ScriptEngine py = Python.CreateEngine();

ScriptScope scope = py.ExecuteFile("Square.py");
//get variable and then create and object. Could be stored somewhere between computations
dynamic squareInstance = scope.GetVariable("SquarePython")(); 

int result = (int) squareInstance.Square(5);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Notes:**  see [VB.Net equivalent for C# 'dynamic'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-sharp-dynamic-with-option-strict-on) if you need to convert `dynamic` keyword to VB.NET