# Initiate two dimensional array from string

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, highcharts

I'm working more than 5 hours on a freaking simple problem I have using Highcharts.NET
Basically all I want to do, is to initiate an array with dynamic data.

I really want to have only this part "{1500,3}" being added from an object, string, list or what ever to the array.

If I'm creating a string with the values "{1500,3}" it tells me of course, that 1 dimension of the array is missing.

This is the part, I need to have dynamically with values from a list / string etc.

```
  TokioData = New Object(,) {{1500, 3}}
```

Comment: What is dynamic data in your case? Could you give an example? Do you need a string to parse (what is the format?) into 2d array?

Comment: If you want to create and modify 2D arrays see: http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array
But please clarify your question, as in its current form it's not really answerable - if there is such a word

Comment: nobody ? :( what a pity

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a list over an array, especially if you want to add / remove values later in your code:

```
    Dim TokioData As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer))
    TokioData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(1500, 3))
    TokioData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(1700, 5))
    TokioData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(1800, 13))
```

One of the great thing about lists are that you don't have to re-declare the size when adding values like you do with an array. There is also built in functionality if you need to convert that list to an array:

```
    TokioData.ToArray()
```

Comment: Believe me, I would never ever use arrays over list. But as I'm using this for highcharts, I need to put this in this freaking object(,) array.

Answer (score -1):

in c# you could use `dynamic` keyword, but not sure if this exist in VB,
but here is link about [dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-sharp-dynamic-with-option-strict-on)