# Calling overloaded method with generic property calls wrong overload

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, overloading

I have a basic filter class that stores a `string` parameter name and a generic `T` value.  The filter has a method `Write(writer As IWriter)` which will write the contents of the filter to an HTML page.  The `Write` method has two overloads, one which takes two strings and which takes a string and an object.  This lets me auto-quote strings.

The problem is, when I call `writer.Write(ParameterName, Value)` and `T` is a `string`, it calls the overload for string/object, not string/string!  If I call the Write method on the `writer` directly, it works as expected.

Here's an SSCE in C#.  I tested this in both VB and C# and found the same problem

```
void Main() {
    FooWriter writer = new FooWriter();

    Filter<string> f = new Filter<string>() {ParameterName = "param", Value = "value"};

    f.Write(writer);                        //Outputs wrote w/ object
    writer.Write(f.ParameterName, f.Value); //Outputs wrote w/ string
}

class FooWriter {
    public void Write(string name, object value) {
        Console.WriteLine("wrote w/ object");
    }

    public void Write(string name, string value) {
        Console.WriteLine("wrote w/ string");
    }
}

class Filter<T> {
    public string ParameterName {get; set;}
    public T Value {get; set;}

    public void Write(FooWriter writer) {
        writer.Write(ParameterName, Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is, when I call writer.Write(ParameterName, Value) and T is a string, it calls the overload for string/object, not string/string!

Yes, this is expected - or rather, it's behaving as specified. The compiler chooses the overload based on the *compile-time* types of the arguments, usually. There's no implicit conversion from `T` to `string`, so the only applicable candidate for the invocation of `writer.Write(ParameterName, Value)` is the `Write(string, object)` overload.

If you want it to perform overload resolution at *execution* time, you need to use dynamic typing. For example:

```
public void Write(FooWriter writer) {
    // Force overload resolution at execution-time, with the execution-time type of
    // Value.
    dynamic d = Value;
    writer.Write(ParameterName, d);
}
```

Note that this could still behave unexpectedly - if `Value` is null, then it would be equivalent to calling `writer.Write(ParameterName, null)` which would use the "better" function member - here `writer.Write(string, string)` - even if the type of `T` is `object`!

Comment: Why is the compile time type of `T` object, not string?  I thought the compiler "magically replaces" all the generics in my program with their concrete equivalents when I compile.

Comment: @just.another.programmer: The compile-time type of `T` is just `T`... but there's an implicit conversion of `T` to `object`, but not from `T` to `string`. `Filter<T>` is only compiled *once* - you need to update your understanding of how generics works,  basically.

Comment: In the case of `writer.Write(f.ParameterName, f.Value)`, the compiler knows `T` is a string.  That has something to do with the declaration `Filter<string> f` I assume?  Any good reading material on what the compiler is actually doing in both cases?

Comment: @just.another.programmer: Yes, because the type of `f` is `Filter<string>`. Compare that with the point at which the compiler compiles `Filter<T>` - it converts that into IL *once*, even though `Filter<T>` can be used in multiple places with different types for `T`. As for the best reading material... I'd thoroughly recommend the C# specification. I don't know whether C# in Depth (my own book) would help on this one - I'd like to hope so, but I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Do you know how to force execution time time overload resolution?  Using `Dim d = Value` (the rough VB equivalent of dynamic) doesn't work.

Comment: @just.another.programmer: That's not really the equivalent of `dynamic`, as far as I'm aware. I suspect you'd need to mess with options (strict/explicit) but I'm not a VB expert.

Comment: @just.another.programmer: [VB.Net equivalent for C# 'dynamic' with Option Strict On](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-sharp-dynamic-with-option-strict-on).