# Vb.net version of a C# code doesn't work

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert this code from C# to VB.net using converters , but the converted code has errors :

```
dynamic DynamicCast(object entity, Type to)
{
var openCast = this.GetType().GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod(to);
return closeCast.Invoke(entity, new[] { entity });
}
```

...

```
Private Function DynamicCast(entity As Object, [to] As Type) As dynamic
Dim openCast = Me.[GetType]().GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.[Static] Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
Dim closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod([to])
Return closeCast.Invoke(entity, New () {entity})
End Function
```

1)  The expression `... as dynamic` is unkown

2 ) The `Me.[GetType]`... produce error ( I have the code in a Module )

3)  In the `...return..` line the expression `New () {entity}` has error : Type expected.

What should I change to correct these errors ?

**Update :**
I have 3 problems in this question. Only one is related with dynamic keyword. So the possible duplicate link doesn't cover my entire question.

Update : 
Sorry friend .You have right , I forget to include the Cast function :

This is the Cast Function on C# version :

```
static T Cast<T>(object entity) where T : class
{
    return entity as T;
}
```

So is there nay changes in your responses ?
Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net equivalent for C# 'dynamic' with Option Strict On](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-sharp-dynamic-with-option-strict-on)

Comment: just remove the `as dynamic`

Comment: @Carsten But what about the 2 other problems ?

Comment: ok I retracted the vote but the rest should be easy: for 2.) the original code was not in a module/static class so why would you bring it into one? for 3.) it's because the syntax is `new with { .entity = entity }` (I don't know if you it works with `{ entity }` alone) - btw: why convert at all?

Comment: I'm converting , because I don't know c# , and for a problem I found this code in C# and I want to convert to VB.Net.

Comment: ok ... but then it should be easy for you to solve these syntax problems ... well anyway just try it

Comment: I don't understand your solution for the problem 2). The solution for 3) doesn't work...... And I get this code from a C# - To VB.net converter. So why these errors ?

Comment: see the *answer* ... but still you should try to understand the code/what it does first - there is just not enough information/code here to really give an answer (as it will never work this way)

Answer (score 2):

ok, this compiles:

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class DynConv

    Public Function DynamicCast(entity As Object, [to] As Type)
        Dim openCast = Me.[GetType]().GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.[Static] Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Dim closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod([to])
        Return closeCast.Invoke(entity, New Object() {entity})
    End Function

End Class
```

but it will not work (because there is no `Cast`) method on the class obvious.

So I think you are missing parts in the original code as well but this *should* be the translation from the C# snippet into something VB.net

what you *maybe* want is something like this:

```
Module DynConv

    Public Function DynamicCast(entity As Object, [to] As Type)
        Dim openCast = GetType(DynConv).GetMethod("Cast", BindingFlags.[Static] Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        Dim closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod([to])
        Return closeCast.Invoke(entity, New Object() {entity})
    End Function

    Private Function Cast(Of t)(input As Object)
        ' ...?
        ' return something
    End Function

End Module
```

but you should really add some intention because I think this is really strange

Comment: Sorry , friend. I forget to include the Cast function. But I have updated now the question and I have include the Cast function. so is there any change in your response ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dynamic.ExpandoObject which serves the same purpose as

```
 Public Function DynamicCast(ByVal entity As Object, ByVal [to] As Type) As Dynamic.ExpandoObject
    Dim c = New Test()
    Dim openCast = Me.GetType().GetMethod("Cast",BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    Dim closeCast = openCast.MakeGenericMethod([to])
    Return closeCast.Invoke(entity, New Object() {New Object() {entity}})

End Function
```

see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-11