# Different object's type in VB.net and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, casting

I have 2 codes in vb.net and C# ( I think they are identical ) :

**C#**

```
class ChildClass
{ }

class MyClass
{
    public ICollection<ChildClass> Children { get; set; }

public MyClass()
{
    Children = new HashSet<ChildClass>() { new ChildClass() };
}
}

T e1<T>(T entity)
    where T : class, new()
{
T copy = new T();
return copy;
   }

void Test()
{
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
dynamic children = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Children").GetValue(myClass);
dynamic child = Enumerable.ElementAt(children, 0);
dynamic copy = e1(child);
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Public Class ChildClass
End Class

Public Class MyClass
    Public Property Children As ICollection(Of ChildClass) = New HashSet(Of ChildClass)
End Class

Public Function e1(Of T As {Class, New})(entity As T) As T
    Dim clone As New T()
    Return clone
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim someClass = New MyClass
    someClass.Children.Add(New ChildClass)

    Dim el = Enumerable.ElementAt(CallByName(someClass, "Children", CallType.Get), 0
    Dim el3 = CTypeDynamic(el, GetType(ChildClass))
    Dim copy = e1(el3)
End Sub
```

Now the last line of each code ( where the E1 function is used )  is producing a different object type :

in c# ---- the **copy** has ChildClass type

in vb.net .... the **copy** has Object type

What should I do in order that the vb.net code to produce a ChildClass type object ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did you try casting it?

Comment: I don't want to cast. I just want that the E1 function to return the same object type as in c# version.so I don't want to change the logic of the code in vb.net.

Comment: @alex: You need to call the same `E1` function.  C# is called with a very specific `T` through the magic of `dynamic`.  You have nothing similar in the VB.NET version.

Comment: Possible dublicate of [VB.NET equivalent of dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-sharp-dynamic-with-option-strict-on)

Comment: @MrPaulch: I think this code proves that all the answers to that question are wrong -- there is no exact equivalent.

Comment: @MrPaulch Can you explain where do you see the duplication here ?

Comment: The problem is that there is no equivalent to `dynamic` in VB.NET. That answer is given to the question I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `dynamic` type in C# tries to mimic the behaviour of the value if the compiler knew its type. Therefore, passing it to a method infers the type arguments from its type at run-time. VB.NET doesn't do such things, `el3` is of type `Object`. One way you can solve it is to remove the generic parameters:

```
Public Function e1(entity As Object) As Object
    Dim clone = Activator.CreateInstance(entity.GetType())
    Return clone
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have already accepted an answer, but, for completeness, I'd still like to answer your question *"How can I do this in VB.NET"*?

The reason for the behaviour is that *generics are a compile-time feature*. At compile-type, the type of `el3` is `Object`, so `T` is resolved as `Object`. The same would happen if you declared `child` as `object` in C#.

Since VB.NET does not have a dedicated late-binding type (`Object` serves as both a regular type *as well as* a late-binding type if Option Strict is Off), you will have to resort to reflection for run-time generics resolution. Basically, you can replace

```
Dim copy = e1(el3)
```

with

```
Dim copy = Me.GetType().GetMethod("e1").MakeGenericMethod(el3.GetType()).Invoke(Me, {el3})
```

which yields the same result as your C# code.

Side note: This is actually how dynamic dispatch was commonly done in C# before the introduction of the `dynamic` keyword.