# What is this thingy called in .net?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I remember a while back, I was working on a web page based on C# razor. There was a response property that served as a kind of pipeline between the controller and the page. I don't know what it was called but it had an interesting property -

basically it works like a dictionary(of string, object) so that you can dump anything in there by any name except you would use it like this:

ThingNameIDontRemember.name = whatever

After adding the stuff I wanted, I think they even showed up in intellisense autocomplete on the other side (unlike what you'd expect from a generic object)

What is that type called and is it also available outside the mvc bundle? I coul'd really use something like that in my current vb.net project.

Comment: _"What is that type called and is it also available outside the mvc bundle?"_ It is the [_`dynamic` type_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) and yes, it is available in any C# or Visual Basic application targeting .NET 4.0+.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`ViewBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag).

> The `ViewBag` property enables you to dynamically share values from the controller to the view. It is a dynamic object which means it has no pre-defined properties. You define the properties you want the `ViewBag` to have by simply adding them to the property. In the view, you retrieve those values by using same name for the property.

More generally, C# 4 introduced dynamic typing using the `dynamic` type - if an expression is of type `dynamic`, binding (working out the meaning of names) doesn't happen until execution time. For example:

```
dynamic d = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(d.Length); // Uses string.Length
d = new int[10];
Console.WriteLine(d.Length); // Uses the array Length
Console.WriteLine(d.Bang()); // Compiles, but will throw at execution time
```

For a general grab-bag, you can use [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject):

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.Foo = 10;
expando.Bar = "Some string";
Console.WriteLine(expando.Foo); // 10
```

There's a lot more to dynamic typing than this, but hopefully that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Keyword for OP's question being "dynamic". Related: [VB.Net equivalent for C# 'dynamic' with Option Strict On](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-sharp-dynamic-with-option-strict-on).

Comment: Indeed, he was probably using `ViewBag` but I think he is actually looking for the `dynamic` type.