# Adding Handler to Dynamic in C# can't convert to VB Object AddHandler

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, delegates, c#-to-vb.net

I have some C# code that I am converting to VB.NET.

In a class I have the following:

```cs
public class ServiceCapServerLib : ICapServerLib
{
    private readonly dynamic _lib;

    public void AddMessageReceivedHandler(ICapServerLib.MessageReceivedEventHandler action)
    {
        _lib.MessageReceived += action;
    }
}
```

My VB Equivalent of this should be:

```vb
Option Strict Off

Public Class ServerCapServerLib
    Implements ICapServerLib

    Private ReadOnly _lib As Object

    Public Sub AddMessageReceivedHandler(ByVal action As ICapServerLib.MessageReceivedEventHandler) Implements ICapServerLib.AddMessageReceivedHandler
        AddHandler _lib.MessageReceived, action
    End Sub
End Class
```

But it fails to compile with "MessageReceived is not a member of Object". This is obviously the case but the C# code works, so am I missing something?

EDIT:
I also tried `AddHandler _lib.MessageReceived, AddressOf action` but this gives the error "'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses)"

Comment: I would consider using an interface, not use any `dynamic`.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic for that in the first place?

Comment: I have to use dynamic because it is utilising late binding on a COM component

Comment: Just remove the `AddressOf`. VB uses `AddressOf` to create a delegate instance from the name of a function. But the identifier `action` names a parameter, which *already is a delegate*. NB: Parentheses seem to be coming and going from the question as it is revised. They shouldn't be used, either, just like the C# version doesn't have them.

Comment: Almost duplicate - [VB.Net equivalent for C# 'dynamic' with Option Strict On](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889974/vb-net-equivalent-for-c-sharp-dynamic-with-option-strict-on)

Comment: **Stop moving the goalposts, please**

Comment: @BenVoigt - apologies I was trying to make things clearer. Hopefully that is now

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - not really a dupe at all because I am happy to use Option Strict Off. In fact you have to use Late Binding

Comment: VB.NET never did have support for late-binding events.  Reflection isn't going to help here either, you'll want to keep this code in a C# class library.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant - When you say something I take it to the bank.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is not valid because the underlying assumption (`dynamic` in C# is the same than `object` in VB.NET with `Option Strict Off`) is not exactly right.

[dynamic in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx):

> The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to bypass
>   compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at
>   run time.

For Visual Studio, `dynamic` variables can be anything and that's why it will never complain about a given property (or event, like in this case). Your first code is fine because it accepts that `_lib` has an event called `MessageReceived` (no check is performed).

---

[Option Strict Off in VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx):

> (when On) Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions,
>   disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in
>   an Object type.

What means that, with `Option Strict Off`, Visual Studio "complains less" in certain situations. To understand the exact implications of the aforementioned not-too-accurate statement, you can either analyse in depth the exact definition of each scenario (e.g., [early & late binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1.aspx)) or believe what Visual Studio tells you. Independently upon the option you choose, you will come to the conclusion that, in this specific situation, `_lib` has to be casted/converted to the corresponding type (`ICapServerLib`) before bringing the event into picture.

---

Note that .NET 4.0 introduced the `System.Dynamic` namespace (at the same time than C# `dynamic`). Both VB.NET & C# can deal with the contents of this namespace without any restriction (e.g., https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504(v=vs.110).aspx).

I don't have too much experience with the aforementioned namespace and am not sure whether you can perfectly emulate the C# `dynamic` behaviour in VB.NET. But I am certain about something: `Option Strict Off + Object` is not the same than `dynamic` in C#. Also note that the VB.NET [WithEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aty3352y.aspx) does not exist in C# and that's why in VB.NET events are treated differently than other properties (unlikely in C#).

---

NOTE: Hans Passant has written a comment to this question highlighting that late-binding events have never been supported by VB.NET. I am not in a position to (fully) confirm/dismiss such a statement, but will assume that it is right. In that case, the intended direct conversion of the original C# code to VB.NET is not possible.

Comment: Thanks I tried that exact code but I still get the error "MessageReceived is not a member of object"

Comment: Yes I tried the exact code you posted: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=43ba972

Comment: @MattWilko I have done some tests with no positive result. I have updated my answer to reflect this issue (and the place where you might find something. System.Dynamic namespace). Note that events are treated slightly different in C# & VB.NET (requiring `WithEvents`) and you would also have to account for this issue.

Comment: @MattWilko I have realised right now that Hans Passant has written a comment above saying that what you are trying to accomplish is not possible in VB.NET. He might be wrong (like everyone), but a so generic statement coming from a so experienced person is quite likely to be true.