# Option strict... with exceptions?

Tags: vb.net, option-strict

I like using option strict, for the "discipline" it forces upon you.
However there are a few cases, you just don't find any option strict compatible code. For example when you use WScript, I know no way but a CreateObject ...
Is there a way to "disable" option strict on a few lines?

Comment: Any chance you can show the code that forces you to turn of Option Strict?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2890050/17034

Comment: To clarify - read the comment by Sehnsucht under the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks all. I made one module only for "non strict" code