# What does improved type-safety means?

Tags: java

What does improved type-safety means?

Comment: You're going to have to give us some context here - are you quoting from somewhere? Improved compared to what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Type-safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260626/what-is-type-safe) ...and/or a couple more posts listed in the _Related_ section on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of type safety from Wikipedia:

> In computer science, type safety is the extent to which a programming language discourages or prevents type errors. A type error is erroneous or undesirable program behaviour caused by a discrepancy between differing data types.

E.G. if you can write a program where you treat a string like a number then you have low (or no) type safety.

Now apply this to the context from which you read/heard the 'improved type safety' phrase. In relation to the definition above 'improved' means 'to a greater extent'.