# typesafe select onChange event using reactjs and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have figured out how to tie up an event handler on a SELECT element using an ugly cast of the event to any.

Is it possible to retrieve the value in a type-safe manner without casting to any?

```
import React = require('react');

interface ITestState {
    selectedValue: string;
}

export class Test extends React.Component<{}, ITestState> {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { selectedValue: "A" };
    }

    change(event: React.FormEvent) {
        console.log("Test.change");
        console.log(event.target); // in chrome => <select class="form-control" id="searchType" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.3.1">...</select>

        // Use cast to any works but is not type safe
        var unsafeSearchTypeValue = ((event.target) as any).value;

        console.log(unsafeSearchTypeValue); // in chrome => B

        this.setState({
            selectedValue: unsafeSearchTypeValue
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="searchType">Safe</label>
                <select className="form-control" id="searchType" onChange={ e => this.change(e) } value={ this.state.selectedValue }>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                </select>
                <h1>{this.state.selectedValue}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it mean typesafe ?

Comment: I guess it means compiled by typescript and check that all variables assignement are allright from their type. We are talking about typescript, of course, not javascript

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Since upgrading my typings to react 0.14.43 (I'm not sure exactly when this was introduced), the React.FormEvent type is now generic and this removes the need for a cast.

```
import React = require('react');

interface ITestState {
    selectedValue: string;
}

export class Test extends React.Component<{}, ITestState> {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { selectedValue: "A" };
    }

    change(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
        // No longer need to cast to any - hooray for react!
        var safeSearchTypeValue: string = event.currentTarget.value;

        console.log(safeSearchTypeValue); // in chrome => B

        this.setState({
            selectedValue: safeSearchTypeValue
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="searchType">Safe</label>
                <select className="form-control" id="searchType" onChange={ e => this.change(e) } value={ this.state.selectedValue }>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                </select>
                <h1>{this.state.selectedValue}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: As of Dec. 2016 one has to use

`event.currentTarget.value`

to get the data from the form.

Comment: Dave, consider updating your example.

Comment: @MartinMajewski I have edited to use currentTarget (http://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/ is a good explanation)

Answer (score 127):

I tried using `React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>` but it led to an error in the editor, even though there is no `EventTarget` visible in the code:

> The property 'value' does not exist on value of type 'EventTarget'

Then I changed `React.FormEvent` to `React.ChangeEvent` and it helped:

```
private changeName(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.actions.changeName(event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: this should be the top asnwer, FormEvent always shows error if I access e.target.value

Comment: This seems to be corrected as I can now successfully access `event.target.value` without issues; it is typed as `string`, so double casting might be necessary depending on the value type used in the concrete situation. For instance `event.target.value as unknown as number`.

Answer (score 26):

In my case `onChange` event was typed as `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>`:

```js
onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
  console.warn('onChange TextInput value: ' + e.target.value);
}}
```

Answer (score 12):

*Update: the official type-definitions for React have been including event types as generic types for some time now, so you now have full compile-time checking, and this answer is obsolete.*

---

> Is it possible to retrieve the value in a type-safe manner without casting to any?

**Yes.** If you are certain about the element your handler is attached to, you can do:

```
<select onChange={ e => this.selectChangeHandler(e) }>
    ...
</select>
```

```auto
private selectChangeHandler(e: React.FormEvent)
{
    var target = e.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    var intval: number = target.value; // Error: 'string' not assignable to 'number'
}
```

[Live demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20handler(e%3A%20Event)%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20target%20%3D%20e.target%20as%20HTMLSelectElement%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D)

The TypeScript compiler will allow this type-assertion, because an *HTMLSelectElement* is an *EventTarget*. After that, it should be type-safe, because you know that *e.target* is an *HTMLSelectElement*, because you just attached your event handler to it.

However, to *guarantee* type-safety (which, in this case, is relevant when refactoring), it is also needed to check the actual runtime-type:

```
if (!(target instanceof HTMLSelectElement))
{
    throw new TypeError("Expected a HTMLSelectElement.");
}
```

Comment: I suppose that is better than casting to any, but you are still using type assertion, and that is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, but since you are entirely certain that `e.target` is an `HTMLSelectElement`, this type-assertion is _safe_, and all subsequent type-checking is inherently safe as well, such as `target.value`. If you want to make it absolutely bulletproof, you could do a runtime check for its type as well, and throw a `TypeError` if `e.target` is not of the correct type. This will never actually happen, but it adds an additional layer of _guaranteed_ type-safety.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260626/what-is-type-safe what I understand by typesafe is that the type checking is imposed by the compiler. That means no type assertions and not depending on runtime exceptions.

Comment: I previously commented that the event handler should be public, not private. I have since realized that was incorrect. Even if we had private methods at run-time (which hopefully we will [in the future](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods)), a private method would still work fine here, because React doesn't need to call the private method directly but only the arrow function you're passing as the `onChange` prop.

Answer (score 10):

it works:

```
type HtmlEvent = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>

const onChange: React.EventHandler<HtmlEvent> = 
   (event: HtmlEvent) => { 
       console.log(event.target.value) 
   }
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to add a type to the variable that is receiving the value, like this:

```
var value: string = (event.target as any).value;
```

Or you could cast the `value` property as well as `event.target` like this:

```
var value = ((event.target as any).value as string);
```

***Edit:***

Lastly, you can define what `EventTarget.value` is in a separate `.d.ts` file. However, the type will have to be compatible where it's used elsewhere, and you'll just end up using `any` again anyway.

*globals.d.ts*

```
interface EventTarget {
    value: any;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to get rid of the "as any" cast completely.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, but that still doesn't answer my question. I think the answer is that the .d.ts of react would need to be modified so that the signature of the onChange of a SELECT element used a new SelectFormEvent. Otherwise as you point out it needs a cast. I guess I could encapsulate that in a MYSELECT tag.

Comment: Okay, don't forget to answer and accept your answer :) [Self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: A better way of adding ```EventTarget.value``` is to augment the global eventTarget, which can be done via any .ts file:
```declare global { interface EventTarget {  value: any; }}```

Answer (score 6):

**JSX**:

```
<select value={ this.state.foo } onChange={ this.handleFooChange }>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

**TypeScript**:

```
private handleFooChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const element = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
    this.setState({ foo: element.value });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this is currently not possible - a cast is always needed.

To make it possible, the .d.ts of react would need to be modified so that the signature of the onChange of a SELECT element used a new SelectFormEvent. The new event type would expose target, which exposes value. Then the code could be typesafe.

Otherwise there will always be the need for a cast to any.

I could encapsulate all that in a MYSELECT tag.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @thoughtrepo's answer:

Until we do not have definitely typed events in React it might be useful to have a special target interface for input controls:

```
export interface FormControlEventTarget extends EventTarget{
    value: string;
}
```

And then in your code cast to this type where is appropriate to have  *IntelliSense* support:

```
 import {FormControlEventTarget} from "your.helper.library"

 (event.target as FormControlEventTarget).value;
```