# Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<{}>' is not assignable - React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using TypeScript (`Version 3.8.3`) and React to build a small website.

I have a component named `MyComponent`. It takes as a prop a function `handleChange`.
However, I am getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>'
```

**The function**

```
  const handleChange = (
    event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    value: MyValue
  ) => {
    setSelectedObj(value)
  }
```

**MyComponent**

```
  <Autocomplete
    ...
    onChange={(event, value) => handleChange(event, value)}
    ...
  />
```

I checked the following similar issue without much success.

[Typescript input onchange event.target.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676343/typescript-input-onchange-event-target-value)

[typesafe select onChange event using reactjs and typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256274/typesafe-select-onchange-event-using-reactjs-and-typescript)