# Material UI Slider and Typescript onChange number | number[] type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to Typescript here. I have a Material UI `Slider` that I'd like to set my `age` state variable with, but I'm getting a Typescript error due to the typing of `age` being `number` and `onChange` value being `number | number[]`. How can I tell `onChange` to always expect a `number`?

code:

```
      <Slider
        defaultValue={25}
        step={1}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        onChange={handleAgeSliderChange}
      />
```

onChange: (use Redux store)

```
    const handleAgeSliderChange = (event:any, newValue: number | number[]) =>{
        const new_inputs = { ...props.userInput, age: newValue}
        props.updateUserInputs(new_inputs)
    }
```

and the error:

```
  Types of property 'age' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

EDIT: Some more details:

in ActionCreators.tsx

```
export const updateUserInputs = (input: UserInputs) : ActionTypes.UserInputActions => ({
    type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_INPUTS,
    payload: input
})
```

in userinputs.tsx

```
const initialState: UserInputs = {
    age: 25, 
    ethnicity: "white",
    country: "US",
    smoking: false
}

export const userInputReducer = (
    state = initialState,
    action: ActionTypes.UserInputActions
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ActionTypes.UPDATE_USER_INPUTS:
          const new_input = action.payload
          return {...state, userInput: new_input}
    default:
        return {...state}    
      }
  };
```

in types.tsx

```
export interface UserInputs {
  age: number;
  ethnicity: string;
  country: string;
  smoking: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what the `updateUserInputs` function looks like? I assume the error comes from there.

Comment: I added some more details. I'm new to Redux & React in general, but everything seems to be hooked up correctly, it's just complaining that `number` doesn't map to `number[]`

Comment: I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256274/typesafe-select-onchange-event-using-reactjs-and-typescript

Tried `var value: number = newValue as any` and it seems to work. Is this best practices?

Comment: No, `any` is the loosest type which kinda makes it pointless to use TypeScript. Instead of `any` you can cast it to a `number`, but this still ignores the scenario of when it potentially is an array of numbers.

Comment: Any idea if there is a better solution that doesn't  involve somehow rewriting onChange?

Comment: In case others end up here from searching on a similar error with the `event` typing from this Slider component, I was able to get it to work with `changeHandler = (event: React.SyntheticEvent | Event, newThresholdValue: number[]) => { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in a change handler like the one below.

```
const handleAgeSliderChange = (_ : Event, value: number | number[]) => {
       const age = Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : value;
       props.updateUserInputs(age);
}
```