# Use response header as part of returned object with Retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, rx-java, rx-java2

I am using Retrofit + RxJava + GSON to consume a rest api for search. The way the API is built, it returns a list of objects and the total results as a header in the response (`total-results`):

```
@GET("search/events?eager=[competition,tv]")
    fun searchEvents(@Query("q") q: String, @Query("category") category: String, @Query("order") order: String): Single<List<Event>>
```

I would like to instead return Single, where SearchResult is:

```
SearchResult {
 var total: Int
var events: List<Event>
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Retrofit is a type-safe restful library. You can have more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210649/meaning-ofa-type-safe-http-client-for-android-and-java-in-retrofit-2-0

Comment: how does that help?

Comment: It means you can do the way you are describing below is the nice solution from @LordRaydenMK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `Single<List<Event>>` modify your interface to return `Single<Response<List<Event>>>`.

The [Response](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html) class contains both the body and the headers returned from the API call.

You can check for success with `response.isSuccessful()` then you can access the body using `response.body()` and the headers with `response.headers()`.

To get your desired output from there you can use `map()` from RxJava.