# Why can't pointer fit variable of different type, even though sizeof is same?

Tags: c++, pointers, types, casting, strong-typing

Why the sizeof any pointer is 4 or 8 bytes, but it cannot fit any different variable? I get error while trying to assign a double pointer an int pointer value.

```
int          *int_ptr{nullptr};
float        *float_ptr{nullptr};
double       *double_ptr{nullptr};
long double  *long_double_ptr{nullptr};
string       *string_ptr{nullptr};
vector<int>   *vector_ptr{nullptr};

cout << "sizeof int pointer is " << sizeof int_ptr;    //8 or 4
cout << "sizeof float pointer is " << sizeof float_ptr;    //8 or 4
cout << "sizeof double pointer is " << sizeof double_ptr;    //8 or 4
cout << "sizeof double double pointer is " << sizeof long_double_ptr;    //8 or 4
cout << "sizeof string pointer is " << sizeof string_ptr;    //8 or 4
cout << "sizeof vector int pointer is " << sizeof vector_ptr;  //8 or 4

double double_num{1020.7};
double_ptr = &int_ptr;      //cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘double*’ in assignment
```

Comment: Because a type is not just for "fitting" a size.

Comment: It may be helpful to read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) about "type system", and [What is Type safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/260626/5376789)

Comment: Is it possible that you intended to write `double_ptr = &double_num`?

Comment: lets say you catch a fish that is of the same size as your cat, then your cat is still a cat not a fish...

Answer (score 3):

C++ is a statically typed language. The language enforces type safety and protects you from mistakes by rejecting arbitrary conversions between unrelated types. The meaning of a type is not wholly described by the size alone.

If an address contains an object of type `int*`, then a `int**` can point to that object. Given that the address contains an object of type `int*`, it cannot possibly also contain an object of type `double`, so there is no meaningful way to convert one of those pointers to another.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are addresses.
Let's say, you have two addresses:

1. 53 Main avenue
2. 85 WrongTurn Road

The first one is the address to a small 2 bedrooms house.
The second is the address is to a mansion, 23 bedrooms, 10 bathrooms, etc...

You cannot expect all people living in the mansion to move into the small house rigth?
but guess what? at the post office, their box sizes is just the same!
That's how they work. They just tell you where to find your variable. Thay are not containers

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. From your example, it is possible to (wrongly, of course, but still possible) write address 2 in a letter that is intended for address 1. In addition, pointers are not only addresses, as you said, they contain additional type information.

Comment: yes, that would be a good example if pointers were type agnostic, in your analogy nothing prevents me to exchange the two addresses

Comment: you could fix it by saying: You have a flyer with advertisment for a butcher and a flyer with advertisment for a bakery. The adresses written on the flyers are just adresses, if you swap them you still can find the houses, but you wont get what you expect, the flyers become useless

Answer (score 0):

This code is illegal because there is no ["implicit conversion"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to map from `&int_ptr` to `double_ptr`, where an "implicit conversion" is defined as something:

> Performed whenever an expression of some type `T1` is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some other type `T2`; in particular:
>
> - when the expression is used as the argument when calling a function that is declared with `T2` as parameter;
> - when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects `T2`;
>     when initializing a new object of type `T2`, including return statement in a function returning `T2`;
> - when the expression is used in a switch statement (`T2` is integral type);
> - when the expression is used in an if statement or a loop (`T2` is bool).
>     The program is well-formed (compiles) only if there exists one unambiguous implicit conversion sequence from `T1` to `T2`.

[I initially suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55573563/2) you use a [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) but this won't work either as using the result of a `reinterpret_cast` between types is only legal if the types differ only by whether their signed, the type being cast *to* is a `byte*`, `char*`, or `unsigned char*`, or the types are "similar" which is defined as:

> - they are the same type; or
> - they are both pointers, and the pointed-to types are similar; or
> - they are both pointers to member of the same class, and the types of the pointed-to members are similar; or
> - they are both arrays of the same size or both arrays of unknown bound, and the array element types are similar.

As you can see none of these situations apply to wanting to cast from the address of `int* int_ptr` to `double* double_ptr`. It's difficult for me to predict your use case for this type of cast within a [strongly typed language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), but perhaps a `void*` is what you're looking for? It could point to *either* a valid `int**`, in which case you could initialize it like this: `const void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&int_ptr)` or a valid `double*` in which case you'd initialize it like this: `const void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(double_ptr)`. Of course in order to use `ptr` you'd need a variable telling you which type it contained, for example:

```
if(is_int) {
    // recover int** (reinterpret_cast<const int* const*>(ptr)) and operate on it
} else {
    // recover double* (reinterpret_cast<const double*>(ptr)) and operate on it
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Vw8uyr)

I should admit at this point that this answer is somewhat contrived. A better solution anywhere this code is used would very likely be a template.

Comment: `reinterpret cast` would lead to undefined behaviour

Comment: @Caleth Depending upon the implementation, you are correct. In an effort to not mislead, I've gone ahead and typed up some further explanation.

Comment: Not depending. You are breaking the strict aliasing rule, it's undefined behaviour. That the particular behaviour you see is what you expect is totally coincidental.

Comment: @Caleth I appreciate your comments. I actually knew `reinterpret_cast` for casting from any pointer type to another type that wasn't a `byte*`... I guess I just went haywire there for a minute. Thanks for steering me back :J