# Is it Legal to reinterpret_cast to a void*

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, double-pointer

I was looking at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast and I noticed that it specifies the legal types we can always cast to:

- `byte*`
- `char*`
- `unsigned char*`

But I did *not* see `void*` in the list. Is this an oversight? My use case requires a `reinterpret_cast` because I'm casting from an `int**` to a `void*`. And I will eventually cast from the `void*` back to an `int**`.

Comment: "it specifies the legal types we can always cast to" This seems like your invention. That page does not say anything similar to that.

Comment: You don't need a `reinterpret_cast` to convert a pointer to `void*`. https://godbolt.org/z/-eIfjl

Comment: I've reopened the question because I didn't see only the top answer applies to this.  Leaving a link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast

Comment: @cpplearner The types are in the Type Aliasing section.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ugh, I knew that. I'm just forgetting like an idiot. Could you just post that as an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux And I've lied to you. Thank you for posting. I gave you a +1, but [Serge Ballesta answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55729272/2642059) felt a little more clear cut to me so I've accepted that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always legal to convert from a pointer to a type to a pointer to a different type *including void*, so if T is a type this is legal C++:

```
T* x;
void *y = reinterpret_cast<void *>(x);
```

In real world it is never used because `void *` is a special case, and you obtain the same value with `static_cast`:

```
void *y = static_cast<void *>(x); // equivalent to previous reinterpret_cast
```

(in fact above conversion is implicit and can be simply written `void *y = x;` - thank to Michael Kenzel for noticing it)

To be more explicit the standard even says in draft n4659 for C++17 8.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast], §7

> When a prvalue v of
>   object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is `static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`.

When you refer to byte and char being the only legal types, it is just that it is legal to *dereference* the converted pointer only for those types. `void` is not included here because you can never dereference a `void *`.

---

To specifically answer your question

> .. I'm casting from an int** to a void*. And I will eventually cast from the void* back to an int**.

The standard guarantees that first one is a *standard* (read implicit) conversion:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv T”, where T is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>   to cv void”. The pointer value (6.9.2) is unchanged by this conversion.

So this is always legal:

```
int **i = ...;
void *v = i;
```

For back casting, standard says (in `static_cast` paragraph):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T”,

So this is also legal

```
int **j = static_cast<int **>(v);
```

and the standard ensures that `j == i`.

Comment: You don't even need `static_cast` in your example. Any object pointer type is implicitly convertible to `void*` (with equivalent cv qualifiers). You only need `static_cast` to cast a `void*` back to an object pointer of a particular type…

Comment: Thanks for a really detailed answer... unfortunately this is going a little different direction from my misunderstanding. As you can see from the last line of the question I'm trying to cast from an `int**` to a `void*`, and back, which I believe does require a `reinterpret_cast`?

Answer (score 6):

Those types are exempt from strict aliasing rules. It does not mean they are the only type you can use with `reinterpret_cast`. In the case of casting an object pointer to another object pointer type, failing to meet the requirements of strict aliasing rules means you cannot safely dereference the result. But you can still cast the resulting pointer back to the original type safely, and use the result as-if it was the original pointer.

The relevant section from cppreference on [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) :

> (Any object pointer type `T1*` can be converted to another object pointer type *cv* `T2*`. This is exactly equivalent to `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(expression))` (which implies that if `T2`'s alignment requirement is not stricter than `T1`'s, the value of the pointer does not change and conversion of the resulting pointer back to its original type yields the original value). In any case, the resulting pointer may only be dereferenced safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules)

When casting back to the original type, `AliasedType` and `DynamicType` are the same, so they are similar, which is the first case listed by the aliasing rules where it is legal to dereference the result of `reinterpret_cast` :

> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type `DynamicType` through a glvalue of type `AliasedType`, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> - `AliasedType` and `DynamicType` are similar.
> - `AliasedType` is the (possibly cv-qualified) `signed` or `unsigned` variant of `DynamicType`.
> - `AliasedType` is `std::byte`, (since C++17)`char`, or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

[[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7.sentence-1):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.

[[basic.compound]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3.sentence-1):

> The type of a pointer to *cv* `void` or a pointer to an object type is called an *object pointer type*.

You don't need to use `reinterpret_cast`, though. Every object pointer type whose pointed type is cv-unqualified is implicitly convertible to `void*`, and the inverse can be done by `static_cast`.

Comment: Thanks for a really detailed answer... unfortunately this is going a little different direction from my misunderstanding. As you can see from the last line of the question I'm trying to cast from an `int**` to a `void*` which I believe does require a `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: No? "Pointer to `int*`" _is_ a pointer to cv-unqualified object type.

Comment: Cancel that, it's the cast from the `void*` to the `int**` that requires a `reinterpret_cast`. You agree with that right? I pirated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55573563/2642059)'s example to demonstrate: https://ideone.com/G4zuwd Unless you know something I don't I'll need a `reinterpret_cast` to assign `ptr`, right?

Comment: "it's the cast from the void* to the int** that requires a reinterpret_cast" is wrong. All you need is a single static_cast: https://godbolt.org/z/Khvn145G5